# WIll Nikon G and D lenses and (new) Tamron lenses all work with a Nikon D7100?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon, nikon-d7100

I am thinking about getting the following:

- Nikon D7100 DSLR Camera Body
- Nikon AF-S DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR
- Tamron SP AF70-200mm F/2.8 Di LD (IF) Macro
- Tamron SP AF 90mm f/2.8 Di Macro 1:1 Lens
- Nikon Nikkor AF 50mm f/1.8 D

is the kit all compatible?

Comment: Download the owner's manual from Nikon.  In the back is a section on lens compatibility that will answer your questions about the Nikkors.  Tamron should be able to tell you what each of their lenses is in Nikon terms.

Comment: Just make sure to get the Tamrons in the right mount.

Comment: That Tamron 70-200 is not a "new" lens. It's been around since 2008 and is a notoriously slow and inconsistent focuser. The "new" Tamron is the 70-200mm f/2.8 SP Di VC USD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all those lenses are compatible with your Nikon D7100. Any lenses with a Nikon mount is compatible.

There are some Nikon cameras that don't incorporate the screw drive mechanism in the body. They will not Auto Focus with lenses that haven't got an internal AF motor.

All these "entry level" cameras have no screw drive and must use lenses with built in auto focus motors: D40    D40X D60 D3000 D3100 D3200 D3300 D5000 D5100 D5200 D5300 D5500

[Nikon DSLR Camera Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Nikon_DSLR_cameras)

[image]